# using all coordinate points in dataset instead of one coordinate point in Nasa-Power API Command

Tags: python, api

API: https://power.larc.nasa.gov/docs/tutorials/service-data-request/api/

This API provides some parameters for a coordinate (latitute and longitute) point. I want to run this api code for all the latitute and longitute ​​in my dataset instead of one latitute and longitute.Latitude and longitude data is in my **df** dataset like below.

| station | long | lat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Station 1 | 50.80 | 60.80 |
| Station 2 | 45 | 47 |

how do i get json or csv files giving parameters for each latitude and longitude?

A single location point is defined in the api command on the website. I want to get parameters for all location points in my df dataframe. I have 123 location as lat and long. I can't write the location one by one. I need to define this location (in for loop) as lat and lot in df.

I tried this command below but I cannot define **locations** in the for loop.

```
lat=df['lat'].values.tolist()
long=df['long'].values.tolist()



import os, json, requests

latitude=lat
longitude =long

output = r"C:/......."
base_url = r"https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/daily/point?parameters=T2M,T2MDEW,T2MWET,TS,T2M_RANGE,T2M_MAX,T2M_MIN&community=RE&longitude={longitude}&latitude={latitude}&start=20150101&end=20150305&format=JSON"

for latitude, longitude in locations:
    api_request_url = base_url.format(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude)

    response = requests.get(url=api_request_url, verify=True, timeout=30.00)

    content = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1]

    filepath = os.path.join(output, filename)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file_object:
        json.dump(content, file_object)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A single location point is defined in the api command on the website.  I want to get parameters for all location points in my df dataframe. I have 123 location as lat and long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can append the `content`s in the `for` `loop` and then save the whole list of `contents` (outside of the `for` `loop`) as a single `JSON` file. Also, the `longitude` and `latitude` coordinates must be correct (i.e. they can't be outside of the possible range of actual coordinate values) otherwise the request will return `<Response [422]>` (which I got from using their example in the documentation...) so if you get that error double-check that the coordinates actually exist (on this planet).

Here I used a small sample dataset of `lat` `long` coordinates as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import os, json, requests
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [32.929, 20.029, 42.011], 'long': [5.770, 15.770, 10.970]})
lat=df['lat'].values.tolist()
long=df['long'].values.tolist()
output = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/JSON/"
base_url = r"https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/daily/point?parameters=T2M,T2MDEW,T2MWET,TS,T2M_RANGE,T2M_MAX,T2M_MIN&community=RE&longitude={longitude}&latitude={latitude}&start=20150101&end=20150305&format=JSON"
contents = []
for latitude, longitude in zip(lat, long):
    api_request_url = base_url.format(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude)
    response = requests.get(url=api_request_url, verify=True, timeout=30.00)
    content = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    contents.append(content)
    filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1]
    filepath = os.path.join(output, filename)
with open(filepath, 'w') as file_object:
    json.dump(contents, file_object)
```

saved file:

[image]

If we want each set of `longitude` and `latitude` coordinates saved as individual `JSON` files, then we can save the `content`s inside the `for` `loop`:

```
for latitude, longitude in zip(lat, long):
    api_request_url = base_url.format(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude)
    response = requests.get(url=api_request_url)
    content = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1]
    filepath = os.path.join(output, filename)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file_object:
        json.dump(content, file_object)
```

If we want to save individual files but the `filename`s conflict (i.e. files with the same name are being overwritten), then we can append an `index` corresponding to the order in which the files are being saved (e.g. `'..._1.json'`, `'..._2.json'`, ...):

```
index = 0
for latitude, longitude in zip(lat, long):
    index += 1
    api_request_url = base_url.format(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude)
    response = requests.get(url=api_request_url)
    content = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1]
    filename = filename[:filename.find('.json')] + '_' + str(index) + '.json'
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file_object:
        json.dump(content, file_object)
```

Comment: A single location point is defined in the api command on the website. I want to get parameters for all location points in my df dataframe. I have 123 location as lat and long. I can't write the location one by one.  I need to define this location (in for loop) as lat and lot in df.

Comment: Right, that's what I demonstrated how to do in the first example I provided. I edited it so that the lat long coordinates are zip'ed to together. If this isn't it be more specific than 'define this location in a for loop'.